# Project/Solution Level Code Snippets for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, project, code-snippets, solution

I'm able to create snippets for visual studio in my documents file. But I'd like some snippets to be distributed to the rest of my team via source control, so some way of including a snippet with a Visual Studio solution would be good.

Visual Studio Code apparently supports [Project Level Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_project-level-snippets), but I can't find any such feature for VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually import snippets from anywhere using the snippet manager. So you could just include snippets in the solution and have your team import them?